# Independence test for values between 0 and 1

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, independence, hypothesis-testing

I want to compare a set of frequencies and determine the p-value of their dependence. One of them is the null distribution of frequencies and the other is the distribution that I want to test. The data look like this:

```
nucleotide   background    selected
1   0.1489113   0.06074766
2   0.1428619   0.04205607
3   0.1189465   0.63084112
4   0.1209048   0.05140187 
5   0.1218093   0.07476636
6   0.1282073   0.04205607
7   0.2183589   0.09813084
```

I cannot use the $\chi^2$ test because the numbers are less than 1. I've tried to take the $\log_2$ of the ratio, but I end up with some negative numbers so the $\chi^2$ is a no go again. How can I conduct a test of independence with these values and compute a p-value?

EDIT, additional informations:

basically i'm working on DNA sequences. i have a background pool of sequences that act like a null distribution and from this background i have selected a number of sequences for a particular biological function. now, i wanted to compare the distribution of mutations in a small sequence of 7 nucleotides in the pool of selected sequences versus the background.

To achieve this, i've taken all the instances where this sequence is present with one mutation in both pools and determined the frequency of mutation for each nucleotide (e.g. number of mutations at a given nucleotide / total number of mutations over all nucleotides), that is how i end up with those frequencies.

now my aim was to show that the pattern of mutation is indeed much different in the selected pool with respect to the background (63% of the mutations in the selected pool happen in the 3rd nucleotide, and the other nucleotides undergo visibly less mutations than in the background)

to provide further information, the selected column describes the frequency of 214 mutations over the 7 nucleotides while the background column describes the frequency of 120508 mutations over 7 nucleotides.

Comment: Do your observations represent the number of events over the same number of trials?

Comment: I can't understand why you would want to use the chi-squared test in the first place. What would it mean for these two sets to be independent? Are you wondering if these vectors are uncorrelated? Are you wondering if the means or SDs of these vectors differ from each other?

Comment: To six significant figures, one can rewrite the rightmost column as (13,9,135,11,16,9,21)/214, suggesting the sample size is a multiple of 214. If so, and if these frequencies represent independent observations, without a doubt--regardless of sample size--they are *not* explained by the null distribution (middle column).

Comment: @whuber i don't know how the hell you managed to determine that the observations were 214 but you are correct. i've edited the question and explained how i obtained the data. I too think that the rightmost column is NOT explained by the middle column; but i wanted some sort of statistical indicator that could tell me how much.

Comment: I've updated the solution

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you forget about the frequencies and work with the raw counts (i.e. don't divide by 214 and 120508).

First put these data into R. You can do it eighter directly or by use of R for Excel (which works only on 32-bit MS Office for Windows). I'll assume you put the 7 counts of background in variable `B`, and 7 counts of selected in variable `S`. Remember, that R is case-sensitive!

Run this code:

```
S<-c(23,123,54,235,23,32,123) #sample data.
B<-c(65,345,65,35,786,43,234) #sample data.
library(dgof) #Required to use a more accurate version of the ks.test.
ks.test(rep(1:7,times=S),rep(1:7,times=B))
```

The subexpression `rep(1:7,times=S)` converts counts into the actual observations by simple replication.

Comment: How do you account for the number of observations? (Answer: you cannot, because they are unknown.) Until you can, *no* test--not K-S, not $\chi^2$--will be applicable.

Comment: @whuber - but this is just what I've written...

Comment: I see now what you intended, Adam. The last paragraph is not very clear. I think you mean to say that *if, in this example,* you have the *raw* counts, then you can apply K-S to them (not to the data as presented in the question). The spirit of the idea is right--$\chi^2$ would work well--but K-S (as far as I know) does not apply to discrete distributions. It also is not at all apparent *how* it would be applied to count data.

Comment: @whuibber: K-S test is about comparing cumulative distribution and I fail to see why it shouldn't apply to discrete distribution case. But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: The KS test *statistic* works just fine for any distribution, but (if I recall correctly) calculation of the p-value assumes the distribution is continuous. Discrete distributions will screw it up.  See the first page of http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Arnold+Emerson.pdf, for instance.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I didn't know about that difficulties. The bottom line of this paper is that the end user should use `ks.test` from the **dgof** package instead of the standard one, and proceed with testing the discrete distributions, just like the problem never existed. Assuming one uses R, of course.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski I have updated the question and added informations about how the data were obtained. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Thank you, this method gives me what i want, however, i would like to understand how the result is achieved. how does this test account for the fact that the total number of trials is so different in the two samples? could you explain a bit how it works? unfortunately i'm not too savvy in statistics. :(

Comment: @Tito. Take a look at [this site](http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/stats/KS-test.html). I believe all answers are better put there than I would have.

Comment: Although it does not matter for these data, because the difference is so obvious, `dgof::ks.test` is *not* applicable to this situation. Its [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dgof/dgof.pdf) appears to state that when comparing discrete distributions, one of them must be a *known* reference and *not* estimated from data. Furthermore, the p-value computed for sets with more than $30$ data values is only approximate and "conservative." In such a case, one is likely better off with a permutation test or a chi-square test (available in base `R`).

Comment: @whuber. Thank you. I didn't know that.

Comment: @whuber i looked up the documentation you gave me on KS-test and concluded that it is not a good test for this situation as well. what i'm comparing is a profile; not a set of measurements of condition A vs condition B. what i'm saying is that the first first datapoint of the background should be compared to the first datapoint in the selected the second in the background to the second in the selected and so on... is it possible to use the spearman correlation as a test of Indipendence in these cases?

Comment: @Tito: From the perspective of KS test your datapoint is the observed occurance of a given SNP, not the bin (i.e. row)

Answer (score 0):

Good comment by Tito, pointing out that you may want to make sure that your frequencies are coming from a number of trials that are similar (ideally identical).

I recommend multiplying each proportion that you have by X, and setting the number of trials to X also.

If you have an identical number of trials for each variable, then X = the number of trials. You can then run your chi-squared. If there are differing numbers of trials, then I'm not sure.

Hope this helps.